# Contact Test Bit Mask not working proper

Tags: testing, sprite-kit, contacts, bitmask

`contactTestBitMask` works in general but if the graphic is too complex `contactTestBitMask` freaks out and you have only a small contact area or get weird errors. What can i do there?

This is an image about my area:

[image]

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
let WallCategory   : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
let ShipCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
var counter = 0
var userCanBuild1Building = false
var KameraSichtVar:SKCameraNode = SKCameraNode()


var touched:Bool = false
var startTouch = CGPointMake(0, 0)
//------------------------------


var draufgeklickt:CGPoint = CGPoint()
var draufgeklicktUpdate:CGPoint = CGPoint()
var userWantScroll = false
var userWantBuild = false
let wohnhausBlue = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"wohnhausBlue")
let buildMenu = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Buildmenu")
var hitDetected = false



let actualBuilding = SKSpriteNode()
var userWantUpgrade : Bool = false
//var theBuildingBefore = SKSpriteNode()
//var houseLvlSave : Int = 0
var uphausSave : String = ""
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var BuildingObject: SKPhysicsBody
    var ClickObject: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
    {
        BuildingObject = contact.bodyA
        ClickObject = contact.bodyB
    }
    else
    {
        BuildingObject = contact.bodyB
        ClickObject = contact.bodyA
    }


    // upgrade Building
    let name = BuildingObject.node!.name
    let HouseLvL: Int = Int(name!)!
    if HouseLvL > 0 && userCanBuild1Building == true{

        userCanBuild1Building = false
        let touchedBuilding = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: BuildingObject.node!.name!)
        touchedBuilding.name = BuildingObject.node!.name

        let name = BuildingObject.node!.name
        var HouseLvL: Int = Int(name!)!
        HouseLvL = HouseLvL + 1

        let uphaus = String(HouseLvL)

        let setSpriteTexture = SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(imageNamed: uphaus))
        let upSize = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: uphaus)
        let resizeHousewidth = SKAction.resizeToWidth(upSize.size.width, duration: 0)
        let resizeHouseheight = SKAction.resizeToHeight(upSize.size.height, duration: 0)



        touchedBuilding.runAction(resizeHousewidth)
        touchedBuilding.runAction(resizeHouseheight)
        touchedBuilding.runAction(setSpriteTexture)
        touchedBuilding.name = "\(uphaus)"

        touchedBuilding.position = BuildingObject.node!.position
        touchedBuilding.zPosition = BuildingObject.node!.zPosition
        touchedBuilding.userInteractionEnabled = false

        let upgradedbuilding = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: uphaus)
        touchedBuilding.size = CGSizeMake(upgradedbuilding.size.width, upgradedbuilding.size.height)
        touchedBuilding.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed:"\(uphaus)"), size: upgradedbuilding.size)


        touchedBuilding.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = WallCategory
        touchedBuilding.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        touchedBuilding.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        touchedBuilding.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

        addChild(touchedBuilding)
        BuildingObject.node?.removeFromParent()
        ClickObject.node?.removeFromParent()






    }


    if HouseLvL == 0
    {
    ClickObject.node?.removeFromParent()
    }




        }`override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    if let KameraSicht:SKCameraNode = self.childNodeWithName("Kamera") as? SKCameraNode{
        KameraSichtVar = KameraSicht
        self.camera = KameraSichtVar


    }


    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)

    func addBG(){

        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "0")
        background.name = "0"
        background.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
        background.zPosition = 2
        background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame)+self.frame.width/4, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)-self.frame.height/4)
        background.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "0"), size: background.size)
        //background.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: background.size)
        background.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = WallCategory
        background.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        background.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        background.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0


        self.addChild(background)

    }

    addBG()


    let wall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"1" )
    wall.name = "1"
    wall.zPosition = 10
    //wall.xScale = 3
    //wall.yScale = 3
    wall.size = CGSizeMake(100, 100)
    wall.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: wall.name!), size: wall.size)
    //wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: wall.size)
    wall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    wall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    wall.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = WallCategory
    wall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    self.addChild(wall)




}
```

`

Comment: i added a picture.. i tried to make a contact between a touch object and the graphic i posted . my code work for every other graphics i tried expect this one. you can use the graphic and try it by your own :D it won't work proper.. or wait.. i post some code

Comment: but as i said the code works fine.. try the graphic i attached and make a contact. I'm pretty sure it won't work proper no matter what code u use :D

Comment: i add even more code.. i hope its not too much now

Comment: No no, it's ok, if you give the opportunity to replicate your issue then you have write a good question.

Comment: Remember: do not use abbreviation like "u" for you, attach remote image here in local because this one could be not available in the future and your question could do not make sense, always report the code that caused the problem to allow others to help you, good luck.

Comment: wow  you need to clean this up and provide the smallest amount of code to replicate your issue,  plus describe your issue better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found the solution. the problem was the weird behavior of the contactTestBitMask when you use this graphic.(it only detected a contact in a small area of the graphic). the reason for that is that the graphic have separated shapes (like the half ring and some other small stuff).

i connected all shape so that its only one shape and now everything works perfectly fine. also tried it with some other graphics and the behavior of contactTestBitMask is: if you have separated shapes in your graphic, contactTestBitMask take exactly one of the shapes and make it the contact area ...but the other shapes in your graphic will not detect a contact then...